# PDO fetchColumn not returning row count

Tags: mysql, pdo

I have a table in my database called posts it contains a row and yet when I do a count on it I'm not getting anything back, not 0 just empty. $numRows contains nothing at all when I echo it out. If you need more info can you please comment and don't just down vote this question.

My question: Is there any reason why this wouldn't work? I'm new to PDO and I'm not sure if this is the way to correctly count the rows.

```
$id = 1;
$STH_ = $DBH->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM posts WHERE owner=:owner");
$STH_->bindParam(':owner', $id);
$numRows = $STH_->fetchColumn();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `$STH_->execute();` to actually run the query.  Call it after your call to `bindParam()`

You should also check for errors.

Comment: It depends on how you setup the connection. I prefer the exception method. See here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Answer (score 1):

you need to [execute](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) the query first like

```
$STH_->execute();
```